# Why won't emacs permanently save my buffer-local var?

Tags: customize, variables, buffer-local

For many files I have file-local variables which asked me once if they were safe and I could add them permanently to my "trusted" list, never to be asked again. However, I get asked every time on the following file variable, and it doesn't give me the option to save it. I even added it manually to my trusted vars, but no luck. Anyone know why?

```
# -*- next-error-function: nil;-*-
;; that was the first line of my file
```

Comment: buffer-local or file-local? Those aren't the same thing.

Comment: Oh.. I didn't realize they were different. Which one goes with the code above?

Comment: file-local is what you show